# Mahout spark-itemsimilarity saveAsTextFile final stage is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, mahout, mahout-recommender, collaborative-filtering

I'm using **Mahout 0.11.0** on **Spark 1.5.1** in YARN client mode on an **HDP 2.2** cluster from the cli. My input is about 325Mb, partitioned into 1000 part files. Here's the exact command I invoke:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout spark-itemsimilarity --input unit-similarity-dump/bpc1 --output mahout-cooccurrence-output4 --maxPrefs 200 --maxSimilaritiesPerItem 100 --master yarn-client --sparkExecutorMem 10g -D:spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 -D:spark.executor.cores=5 -D:spark.executor.instances=50 -D:spark.yarn.am.memory=4g -D:spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=512 -D:spark.yarn.am.cores=2 -D:spark.driver.memory=20g -D:spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 -D:spark.driver.cores=4 -D:spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g -D:spark.yarn.queue=product -D:hdp.version=2.2.6.0-2800
```

The applications hums along nicely until the final stage, in which `saveAsTextFile` gets called. At this point, the tasks grind to a halt, each taking somewhere between 45 mins to an hour to succeed. Upon closer inspection, it seems that each task is reading all 1000 partitions of the **MapPartitionsRDD**, which I think, intuitively, must be the source of the performance issue. These partitions are spread somewhat evenly across all of the executors, so I would think each task would need to request all the partitions from the n-1 executors that aren't its direct parent.

What's the best way to optimize this application? Less partitions, so there's less remote data to request? Less executors, so a higher percentage of data is localized for every task? Try to force a higher replication factor for the RDD? Right now it seems to be defaulting to **Storage Level: Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated**, 100% cached.

Here is a screenshot of the stage details for clarity: [saveAsTextFile stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8dpM.png)

Thanks in advance for any insights.

**Update:**

I tried using just 1 executor with multiple cores (i.e. tasks), and although all of the RDD partitions are present on a single, local executor, the performance is still very slow. I think the only culprit left is the shuffle caused by `reduceByKey` in the final `saveAsTextFile` DAG.

**Second Update:**

I also tried using just 1 input partition, whereas I'd previously been using 100 or even 1000. The results were quite similar, and are summarized [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d14UF.jpg). For clarity, in this run I used a single 20g executor with 5 cores. This approach did, however, result in about an order of magnitude less aggregate resource allocation (as measured in MB-seconds and vcore-seconds). This is probably due to the over-allocation of executors and threads in previous runs, and implies that the bottleneck may not be computation-bound.

Comment: Is there any further update on your issue? Have you fixed it? I am facing the same issue with spark 1.6.3 and Mahout 0.13 and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I follow all the description above. There is a BiMap Bi-directional dictionary that converts column and row ids from the ordinal Mahout id to the string external id. These data structures are in-memory and amount to 2 hashmaps per type of id (row/column). The reduceByKey works on the Mahout ids so the translation happens only during input and output. These data structures are read into the driver then broadcast to each node, only one copy is made per node where the BiMap (actually BiDictionary) is shared by executors.

The partitioning is set to "auto" by default. Which in Mahout 11 should be a value optimized for the cooccurrence calc, and is why things "hum along".

The final step *after* the reduceByKey takes each value in the remaining matrix (row key, vector), converts each id for key and vector element back into strings and writes out the text to the files in parallel.

Frankly I have found the read and write of text files to be hugely dependent on hand tweaking. My main experience was in reading in parallel where Spark reads in all file stats before partitioning--all. This is incredibly slow vs taking 1000 files and concatenating them unto one before reading (try it yourself, they may have fixed this).

It sounds to me like you need a better `saveAsTextFile`. Hand tweaking of the `saveAsTextFile` might be better done with your own distributed operation, a `foreach` works after some repartitioning of the RDD based on your own parameters. See the docs here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd

If you want to experiment, subclass TextDelimitedIndexedDatasetReaderWriter to provide your own writer Trait. Mahout has a `mapBlock` operation that can be used too. It passes a block of rows to each `mapBlock`, which you can write using the BiMap to convert ids.

Would love to hear any results on the Mahout User list.

Comment: Hi Pat. Firstly, thanks for your answer, and secondly, I'm a big fan of Occam's Machete and your work in the space of collaborative filtering. Thanks for all of your contributions! After digesting your answer and digging in further, I think the final BiMap int <-> string may be what's requiring so much resources. I have 1.2M unique ids total, 415k rows, each with up to 100 similarities, and my app-specific ids are strings in the neighborhood of 20 chars long. While this doesn't seem too "big", I think it's the culprit as all the task time, according to the UI, is spent in executor computation.

Comment: The runtime of the Bimap is O(log(n)) complexity, which is better that O(n), our usual measure of goodness. Here n is the number of non-zero matrix elements. The BiMap is just two HashMaps and only one is used for Int->String lookup in the write operation. For the reverse lookup we could probably use an array since the Ints are ordinal Mahout IDs, so a topic for optimization. I still suspect it is a matter of partitioning and that is determined by how many files were used as input. To test this concatenate your input files into a single file and run the job again.

Comment: Using just 1 input file had a small effect on wall clock time for the application, but didn't affect it much overall. Most notably, task times in stage 18 were still in the 45-60 minute range, albeit there were fewer of them to carry out (due to having fewer partitions overall). One thing of note was a large increase in stage 17's time. With 100 partitions, the stage took 46 seconds to complete. With 1 input part file, which resulted in 4 RDD partitions, and hence 4 tasks, stage 17 took 20 minutes to complete. I've updated the question with the pertinent job stats for your perusal.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying the problem is, BiMap lookup or saveAsTextfile?

Comment: I'm saying that, based on the experimental evidence, it doesn't seem like the input partition count has any effect on the performance of the final `saveAsTextFile` stage's tasks, although it clearly affects the performance of stage 17 (which is not the point of this post, but perhaps interesting nonetheless). Also interesting, in my opinion, is the near equivalent wall clock time for the entire app when I use just 1 partition with minimal executor horsepower, vs many partitions with maximal horsepower. This leads me to believe the performance bottleneck is neither CPU nor memory-bound.

Comment: With a little more tinkering, and a proper education in resource utilization monitoring (and a better understanding of executor/task count optimization wrt input/output partition count) I can say with certainty that stage 18's tasks, and hence wall clock times, are **definitely** CPU-bound. Apologies for my earlier pontifications. They were incorrect. Given that I now understand how to optimize to have 1 available executor thread per stage 18 task, I can tinker with the input partition count to squeeze the most parallelism I can out of my computing hardware (i.e. available vcores).